# How can I create an animating GIF 2D illustration in 3D?

Tags: after-effects, animation, motion-graphics

[image]

How can I create any 2D animation to do this type of animation? What programs can I use?

I have AfterEffects and Cinema4D. I am not too well-versed in these platforms. It would be great if you can recommend the best workflow for this. :)

Comment: You need to ask specific questions.

Comment: I don't see the question here. Load up c4d, create a fancy animation, export it as a gif.